# Why does this method fail?

Tags: java, arrays, collections

Recently ran into this question in an interview.  Given an array of integers, find the smallest integer x that can be used as a starting point so that when you add each number from the array to the running total, the running total never goes below 1.  The function stub they gave me, for Java, took in a list collection and I was supposed to return a long.  This solution to me seems like it has to work, but failed every test case.  Why?

```
public static long minStart(List<Integer> arr) {
    long minStart = 0;
    long runningTotal = minStart;
    for(int i = 0; i<arr.size(); i++){
        runningTotal += arr.get(i);
        if(runningTotal<1){
            minStart++;
            i = 0;
            runningTotal = minStart;
        }
    }
    return minStart;
}
```

Comment: Why do you increment minStart variable?

Comment: You assume that the minimum starting int is at least zero. Could it be negative?

Comment: Why not make a running total of the array and find the minimum total. Then make your starting int equal to the negative of that minima.

Comment: I increment minStart so that I can find the starting point.  The starting point, or minStart, must be a positive integer and must be the smallest one possible to ensure the runningTotal never goes below 1.  My idea was to start low and move higher, so that the first value that works must be the minimum possible value

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem here is the `if` block - you should not have one.

I also suspect you misunderstood the question, which I read as *return 1 - the minimum of the running total*.

Something like this:

```
public static long minStart(List<Integer> arr) {
    long total = 0; // long to avoid integer overflow
    long min = Long.MAX_VALUE;
    for (int n : arr) {
         total += n;
         min = Math.min(min, total);
    }
    return 1 - min;
}
```

---

To further reduce the amount of code, you could replace the loop with just:

```
for (int n : arr)
     min = Math.min(min, total += n);
```

This may or may not impress, depending on your audience.

Comment: Thank you for your code.  For the if statement my initial solution - why exactly should I not have one? Is the reassignment in the if block not being performed?

Comment: You should not have the if block because you should not do anything special if the running total drops below 1. Further, you should not be updating your answer  within the loop. You should *first* find the minimum of the running total,  *then* take it away from 1 to get the answer..

Comment: your solution works.  i am still confused as to why my code returns the results that it does.  for example, the array [-5,4,-2,3,1,-1,-6,-1,0,5].  Your solution returns 8, which is correct.  i understand why.  I do not understand why my solution returns 3.  The if statement should catch after -5 is added, and then increment minValue until it is at 6.  While I understand your solution to be the best way to solve the problem, I am curious why mine executes the way it does

Comment: @James your code attempts to restart the loop by setting i to zero, but i is incremented *before* the next iteration, so i will be 1, not zero and so you skip the first element, which is -5 and your answer is out by 5... that’s not a coincidence. Instead, do `i = -1`. Your approach is also flawed because it may loop zillions of times and does not allow minStart to be negative.

Comment: When the result is supposed to be the starting point for the running total, but the running total is supposed to be never smaller than one, this result number must be at least one, as otherwise the constraint would be violated even before the operation started. Also, for an empty list, the result should be just one.

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is that in your for loop, you use `i = 0;` to reset, but then on the very next iteration, the for loop is going to increment `i` to equal 1, which means you skipped over the first number in the list.  I would just try simply changing that line to be `i = -1;`.